# Attach file(pdf) to Gravity Form Notification

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm trying to attach a file to the notification being sent to the user using the gform_notification method. I've literally tried all the examples given on the forum, but nothing seems to work. The notifications are recieved by the user, but the file is not being attached.

The question is a duplicate from this post. But the solution in the post does not work for me. [How do I attach a pdf file to a Gravity Forms Notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260420/how-do-i-attach-a-pdf-file-to-a-gravity-forms-notification)

The file has to be pulled from the server .i.e Media section Wordpress.

```
function change_user_notification_attachments( $notification, $form, $entry) 
{
  if( $notification['name'] == 'User Notification')
  { 
    $attachments = array();
    $attachments[] =RGFormsModel::get_upload_root().'/2017/12/myfile.pdf';
    $notification['attachments'] = $attachments;
  }
return $notification;
}

add_filter( 'gform_notification_25', 'change_user_notification_attachments', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: `RGFormsModel::get_upload_root().'/2017/12/myfile.pdf'` file available on server?

Comment: Yes it is present in the uploads. Solved it myself, the reason the files were not being attached was due to the file size!